# Paper.js Ignoring an image selection

Tags: javascript, paperjs

I'm working with [Paper.js](http://paperjs.org) and I'm trying to build ***"Selection-Via-Intersection"***

Elaborating on what I mean is that the user draws a *selection rectangle* and the items that have their outlines intersecting OR any of their points within the *selection rectangle* get selected.

Now all is well with path items, but a Raster image poses issues:

**Is their a way to either ignore the Raster image in the selection OR make it work in some way with the Raster**(if yes I would appreciate a simple answer otherwise I won't be able to implement it, amateur and all).

With my current code Chrome returns: *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined*

**This is the code so far:**

```
// Returns path points which are contained in the rect. 
function getSegmentsInRect(rect) {
    var segments = [];

    function checkPathItem(item) {
        if (item._locked || !item._visible || item._guide)
            return;
        var children = item.children;
        if (!rect.intersects(item.bounds))
            return;
        if (item instanceof paper.Path) {
            for (var i = 0; i < item.segments.length; i++) {
                if (rect.contains(item.segments[i].point))
                    segments.push(item.segments[i]);
            }
        } else {
            for (var j = children.length-1; j >= 0; j--)
                checkPathItem(children[j]);
        }
    }

    for (var i = paper.project.layers.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        checkPathItem(paper.project.layers[i]);
    }

    return segments;
}

// Returns all items intersecting the rect.
// Note: only the item outlines are tested.
function getPathsIntersectingRect(rect) {
    var paths = [];
    var boundingRect = new paper.Path.Rectangle(rect);

    function checkPathItem(item) {
        var children = item.children;
        if (item.equals(boundingRect))
            return;
        if (!rect.intersects(item.bounds))
            return;
        if (item instanceof paper.PathItem) {
            if (rect.contains(item.bounds)) {
                paths.push(item);
                return;
            }
            var isects = boundingRect.getIntersections(item);
            if (isects.length > 0)
                paths.push(item);
        } else {
            for (var j = children.length-1; j >= 0; j--)
                checkPathItem(children[j]);
        }
    }

    for (var i = 0, l = paper.project.layers.length; i < l; i++) {
        var layer = paper.project.layers[i];
        checkPathItem(layer);
    }

    boundingRect.remove();

    return paths;
}

// Returns bounding box of all selected items.
function getSelectionBounds() {
    var bounds = null;
    var selected = paper.project.selectedItems;
    for (var i = 0; i < selected.length; i++) {
        if (bounds == null)
            bounds = selected[i].bounds.clone();
        else
            bounds = bounds.unite(selected[i].bounds);
```

**And this is how I define my Raster**

```
function placeImage() {

    var raster = new paper.Raster('mona');
    raster.addChild;
    raster.position = paper.view.center;
    raster.selected = true;
    raster.index = 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `item.type` to check if the item that intersected the *Selection Rectangle* is a *''Raster''*.

I added an extra `IF` statement that does just that.

```
IF(item.type === "Raster"){
return;
}
```

This way the items that have a type of *Raster* are ignored.

However if there is a simple way to have a *Raster* get selected with the *Selection Rectangle*  it would be an even better answer, although the solution i suggested solves the question.

**UPDATE: Paper.js v0.9.17 uses [className](http://paperjs.org/reference/item/#classname) instead of type to identify the type of item.**

Therefore the function above changes to this:

```
IF(item.className === "Raster"){
    return;
    }
```